# gpg command line: no public key

Tags: windows-11, gpg4win, kleopatra

Trying to use command line to encrypt a file:

```
>gpg --list-keys

pub   ...
uid           [ultimate] john12345
sub   ...


>gpg -r john12345 -e foo.txt

gpg: john12345: skipped: No public key
gpg: foo.txt: encryption failed: No public key
```

It works with Kleopatra GUI for encrypting a file. The key was created using the Kleopatra GUI.